# Getting error after integrating the flutter_quill_extensions in Flutter project on windows

Tags: flutter, dart

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt\winrt/impl/Windows.Foundation.0.h(1004,26): error C2039: 'wait_for': is not a member of 'winrt::impl' [C:\Users\Tom\Downloads\iact_native-flutterpocs-be215d872058\iact_native-flutterpocs-be215d872058\player_poc\build\windows\x64\plugins\gal\gal_plugin.vcxproj]

I would like to get the resolution of this error.

Comment: I am using flutter_quill: ^8.6.4 and flutter_quill_extensions: ^0.7.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing latest version of winrt

https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt

Make sure visual studio build tools are properly installed

Comment: Thank You!! It helped and saved my time.